# span under div, want span to disappear when hovered over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div class called overlay, it's just a transparent box. When you hover over the live-box div, the span class should disappear (right now its going under the overlay box), and the text "test" appears and an arrow under that appears (working).

So basically everything works but the text in the span jumps under the overlay div, I have tried a few jquery attempts, but because of the fade in/fade out, even if I do a toggle visible class,the text still jumps under the overlay div for half a second.

```
<div class="live-box-outer">
    <div class="live-box" id="CMS">
        <div class="overlay" style="display: none">
            test
            <div class="arrow">
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="long-span">Content Management</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript

```
 $('.live-box').hover(function () {
    $(this).not('.active, .invisible').find('.overlay').fadeIn(300);

}, function () {
    $(this).not('.active, .invisible').find('.overlay').fadeOut(300);
});
```

my css

```
.overlay
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 134px;
    height: 134px;
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
    background: url(../img/overlay.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set long-span within its own div (display: block;) and onhover set the display of that div to none?  You could also set another div(with text to be displayed) with a display of none, and change it to block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have:

```
.live-box-outer {
  position: relative;
}
.long-span {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

What you want then is for the `overlay` and `long-span` to both be position the top left of `live-box-outer`.  Try changing the two such that

```
.overlay, .long-span {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Then when `overlay` fades in it will cover `long-span`.  The other option is to fade/hide `long-span` at the same time you fade/show `overlay`.